# Restoring subscribed purchase for Auto-Renewable Subscriptions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

When I purchase a previously purchased **"Auto-Renewable Subscriptions"** in my app, it said

```
You're currently subscribed to this...
```

When I clicked the OK, in the delegate of the payment queue..

```
- (void) paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction * transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction]; // Why this is called?
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The **transaction.transactionState** returned is **SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed**  instead of **SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored**, is it normal?

So how do I handle this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same issue and I don't think there's any way to distinguish this event from other errors (it returns error code `SKErrorPaymentCancelled`). I think the only way you can handle it is by having a "Restore Purchases" button, and call `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]` when the user presses it.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can't determine if the user is already subscribed. You should have **Subscribe** button that new users use to subscribe, and **Restore** button for already subscribed users.

And when you get `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed` you can show a message that suggests to use **Restore** button in case the user is already subscribed.